# C++ RSA encrypt/decrypt with XML key

Tags: c#, c++, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I need a C++ program running on my Linux server to communicate with my C# application through RSA encrypted messages. The C# part is easy through `RSACryptoServiceProvider` but it only supports keys in XML format like:

**Private Key**

```xml
<RSAKeyValue>
    <Modulus>jhU5nGfGNopA6bHb6nxqTj3/AvPsyZnep6BTSMFyCZLtP4VRu9a/xFaYH6M6SBSf8Aod8Ljjz5aWtet9DPujC1tdG2AmDpkn/6TiUShYbYFNueB25IJoGmNfZdJl3XEWQS0pdrq0wqwgFG4GE3l8gMV6Y/gEnqBx/HZmZOv4JlbkTaQX6KIB8Sxc1zqiAQDV1uTHORG9d6Rh/Rrrv+XntGbKfx75cqU2Q6Ie+o7QoXBSkiRUgb7VlP3NlwBW9VQ03rENpovHhwLvqHbOlV90HPbl0d/JUqmBPTRLe+P+iCLPt76WE1k2Nb9mQzs8fbJ+jrfXtSqSUieeG9B+uz7pxw==</Modulus>
    <Exponent>EQ==</Exponent>
    <P>qP5inK0zFPNqViqpu1dTIrvtD2Ep29YKlnDdnYEwlRjf0VCn/IMfC4lMggOvqmh7FifwJ+GYo+9PLY6pDo5+EAjE1Lna1GRFyrd3smO9scUbAf0Zq2eqhsJjbVBdBQFX2LnARBhpVvevF7wrMpvCYhC6KmhzGrjfmhadDSSfmnU=</P>
    <Q>1zv1p5pWfN3208zp7lIDJPmLa5tO+LEMUsKg4qPFjUif2uI1++HWFCjT6OS9PS48FXv2xdWA/P3jOTw7DSK7SJX5HVBl6T6QV87jkqUtyYFxLAAVxRpGGDy6f+lVs+NyTjmQ7s2zk+Qm7DzGiUoe6BeMU0jXr/KZ4WmvOiy908s=</Q>
    <DP>T4bE/m+fkWN9Vbm5SRoJAUlgf7VA3+xBN7ykhlrpr5M8JkQS0S6lMpr208V/17iyZMeAEsSEEOkWM45trH9KYeYCRf0brz4+9fv8F7Z3YrcbxLNXX7hQP2qJJGINqAChz2Z4mIP1Vho0R2eb25SXta2EyKmflBrDk85oBi9aKpE=</DP>
    <DQ>S/cLaFSW/uTttCo0cjsQKyrl6b5YG4nIHTWiMd9y5pIaTUDHwk+0+A5o6Mkzuz1+nivAgg8ed2iqjKvYmzlvRsuFGWerf39+PRvX2Wd5kmnrtS003CdkCI3neHB4mdfN/X26rqL0FhRJ+QZkMHSDYPlAld15TShyi8ryjQC7d+0=</DQ>
    <InverseQ>d7/VKPzww1KBb0Q6AR8xJrQrbUi1ayVrhB1UQC3K/T1o5xGaEUpkTM+DmPDYi4WMQxhDaalu8II0y1tHMsmZsFy05+VLg8c8BSE9Qn0qOgLxBBYHYqh96kGQqglV1n8s76EHxNZ0aMgpEmipoenqyYgMInCGp5rmmaFeU8hxqsM=</InverseQ>
    <D>GRLN7myqghhlzuMmzwbllVY8D5R1FISQtCtZ/cfI1INXCzWlAwfHfQA49oY3diHB3xDYG2vr93Tta2XKxg5J8vIBXy8VxldDSzs2/0Na5iXgijarkbyo9ZkQ1bu3n4xtVsu8BeS2fLT2mjGImgZhQ+adILNMG/4yO5xsbCmkQwACmf5Shdci2G8nGGjCadLNyamzGcChk9y69mbl0Awx4XQUZ888a9PHv1Mfxvbs48ZSKgrV54aQ0lESJAT7Zl8XzwzIoxxNCiYGFRPrGMkr6ZpcrRAPrFzcoYt6C65XlUvhjBNNvLBJiFZco7KeOOiu5ObTplSqww+rwRdVEq9SCQ==</D>
</RSAKeyValue>
```

**Public Key**

```xml
<RSAKeyValue>
    <Modulus>jhU5nGfGNopA6bHb6nxqTj3/AvPsyZnep6BTSMFyCZLtP4VRu9a/xFaYH6M6SBSf8Aod8Ljjz5aWtet9DPujC1tdG2AmDpkn/6TiUShYbYFNueB25IJoGmNfZdJl3XEWQS0pdrq0wqwgFG4GE3l8gMV6Y/gEnqBx/HZmZOv4JlbkTaQX6KIB8Sxc1zqiAQDV1uTHORG9d6Rh/Rrrv+XntGbKfx75cqU2Q6Ie+o7QoXBSkiRUgb7VlP3NlwBW9VQ03rENpovHhwLvqHbOlV90HPbl0d/JUqmBPTRLe+P+iCLPt76WE1k2Nb9mQzs8fbJ+jrfXtSqSUieeG9B+uz7pxw==</Modulus>
    <Exponent>EQ==</Exponent>
</RSAKeyValue>
```

I therefore need a C++ (gcc) RSA cryptography library that supports these keys and works on Linux. I found [one library](http://code.google.com/p/rsa/) but it seems to be using a very peculiar standard where key length is measured in digits instead of bits and the only difference between its keys is the exponent while the C# standard has the exponent as being the same value in both keys.

Anyone know of a library that I can use?

Comment: FWIW, the format used for the private key won't normally matter, because only that application will use it. The public key is all somebody else will normally use to send encrypted messages. Private keys should be kept...private.

Comment: This doesn't look terribly difficult to x-late. The XML tokens are remedial, and the content appears to be nothing more than bas64 of the actual bits. Any reasonable XML DOM should be able to read these, the crypto library's base64 decoder (or your own or 3rd party) should be able to decode the base64, and from there its just loading the rights blobs in the right places of your lib. So you're looking for something that already does that for you? And I find it hard (but not impossible, knowing MS) to believe that .NET can't export to PEM, in which case any crypto lib would eat it natively.

Comment: crypto++ is a library I have used to good effect previously. http://www.cryptopp.com/

Comment: @WhozCraig and JerryCoffin that's rather obvious but my problem is that if the relationship between keys expected by the libraries differ then I might mean they have a completely different ideas of how RSA works and that leads me to wonder if converting the keys will even be worth it

Answer (score 1):

RSA is a standardized algorithm. That is, actually you have RSA as defined in PKCS#1 v1.5 and there is RSA OAEP defined for encryption. So you need to synchronize the exact RSA algorithm used by a library. Some libraries also support "raw" RSA, that is: only the modular exponentiation part, but that is insecure. Note that for RSA the result is defined as octet string (aka byte array) which makes it very inter-operable.

The library that you point to seems to be a one man project hosted on Google code. That does not seem to be promising, I would stick to libraries such as OpenSSL, CryptoPP or Botan which have survived for some time in the field and have an active community.

You can simply extract the numbers from the XML and use them for any library. You do not strictly need all the parameters, just providing the `Modulus`, `Exponent` and `D` value should be enough. Note that `Exponent` in above is just the public exponent and `D` is the private exponent. The public exponent is normally included in an RSA private key (and can actually be used for internal validation by a crypto library). Beware that different libraries may use different notations.

Note that instead of relying on RSA directly you could also use a *container format* such as CMS (aka PKCS#7).